# How can I customize the MediaRouteButton's and RouteDialog's style?

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm develop an Android Sender application for **googlecast**. In the [design_checklist](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist) page, I noticed that: the `MediaRouteButton's` image has been customized, also the dialog's style is customized. They are not the same to the default style.

BUT, in the `android-support-v7-mediarouter` library , I did NOT find any functions to allow me to customize them.

In [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) project, I found some yellow cast icons , they are same to the picture showed before. But they do not be used in the project.

**Is there a sample project used customized style?
Or how can I customize them?**

Thanks.

**UPDATE：**
I gave up, finally choosed the default style.

Comment: https://github.com/googlecast/cast-button-polymer/blob/master/cast-button-polymer.html

Comment: @RobertRowntree, it is not for android. Thanks any way :)

Comment: That'd be handled in the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android), but I don't see what customization you're referring to. If it looks different now, it's probably because the pictures in the design checklist are slightly old.

Comment: @Andy , the different places are two points : 1.the cast button's drawable. Orignal drawable is white/black, but checklist is yellow.
2.chooserdialog's title's color.

maybe the checklist is too old...CCL gives me a greate help.